# How can we claim drivers without Internet?

Tags: internet, ubuntu-drivers

I turned on my laptop and several drivers are unclaimed, including wifi and both USB-B ports. The USB-C port is working and I'm able to use the trackpad. It's also recognizing my flashdrive. My bag fell over the other day with the laptop in it, though it was in a case. I'd like to know what I can do diagnostically to see what needs to be done. There's no visible external damage and the OS (18.04.1) is running fine. I typed in:

> sudo lshw -C network

This was returned:

> *-network UNCLAIMED
>
> ```
>  description: Network controller
>
>  product: Wireless 3165
>
>  vendor: Intel Corporation
>
>  physical id: 0
>
>  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>
>  version: 79
>
>  width: 64 bits
>
>  clock: 33MHz
>
>  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
>
>  configuration: latency:0
>
>  resources: memory: d1000000-d1001fff
> ```

There is no Ethernet port on my laptop. I'm wondering if I can connect via a wired connection to my phone's hotspot, although I'd probably need to download a driver.

Edit: interestingly, when I'm in BIOS, I can use my wireless mouse which infers that it is not physical damage.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:382 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi' // modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: Thanks. The // denotes a new line in the output.

Comment: Also, updated the capability section of lshw in the original question

Comment: My apologies for my error. I meant to ask for: `dmesg | grep iwl` Sorry.

Comment: Nothing. I spoke with a member of the IT department and they suggested I download the drivers onto a USB flash and install them manually. A far cry from the usual process of uninstalling and reinstalling!

Comment: Tell the IT department that the correct driver *iwlwifi* is already present in a proper 18.04 installation. What does this report: `sudo updatedb && locate iwlwifi.ko`

Comment: Also, when I run lshw in terminal, there are several other unclaimed devices. Here's which: display, generic 0-4, communication, network, memory, multimedia, serial, and volume 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87966/discussion-between-chili555-and-david-e-farmilant).

Comment: Also, I'm running a skeleton crewed Ubuntu. No gParted and several others I can't think of right now.

Comment: Please join me in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our chat, we searched your system for the correct driver *iwlwifi.* We found that it was present in kernel versions 4.15.0-36 and -38 but not the kernel version you were then running, -39.

I suggested that you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and, under Advanced options for Ubuntu, select -38 to see if the wireless was then working as expected. It was.

I suggested that you allow Update Manager to run and update your system, hoping that an even newer kernel version would be installed. It was, that is, 4.15.0-43. When you rebooted into -43, the wireless also worked as expected.

Since the *iwlwifi* module didn't exist in -39, but did in -38 and -36 and, obviously, in -43; I suspect that the update to -39 went wrong somehow; the correct driver(s) were not properly installed. A clue was given in your original comments: "Also, when I run lshw in terminal, there are several other unclaimed devices. Here's which: display, generic 0-4, communication, network, memory, multimedia, serial, and volume 0." Evidently, many other drivers were not correctly installed.

I am glad your wireless is now working as expected.

Comment: The best professional answer. I read all of chat messages and it solved my same problem. Thanks a lot!